# Typescript boolean extends Record<"valueOf",unknown> but not Record<string,unknown>?

Tags: typescript

```
type A = boolean extends Record<"valueOf",unknown> ? true : false // true
//   ^?

type B = Record<"valueOf",unknown> extends Record<string,unknown> ? true : false // true
//   ^?

type C = boolean extends Record<string,unknown> ? true : false // false
//   ^?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBGB7FAbCBDAdlCAHsBDgCYDOUAShAMYoBOpAPAEQBuW6ArhAPIAzVgBpuOANY4UAdxwA+KAH4owBrygAuKAK7loAen0q1EALAAoQ1GsA9RRYuhIUAEIJqdRiw5degkWKSMvL4RCQUHvRMzOSqAJY4AOaiElKyCsqq6lo66HpQVllmlka29uaO4NAAwu6oGNh4hMRklDRRLLEMCcmBaSGZJpraugZGuXoWVmUO5kA)

If

1. `boolean` extends `Record<"valueOf", unknown>` and
2. `Record<"valueOf", unknown>` extends `Record<string, unknown>`

why not `boolean` extends `Record<string, unknown>`??

Comment: Booleans don't have an index signature. You can't use any string to index into them. But you can use `valueOf`.

Comment: Also note that the [assignability relation in TypeScript is not transitive](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47331#issuecomment-1010457038), so the fact that `X extends Y` and `Y extends Z` does not necessarily imply `X extends Z`. (accidentally posted this as an answer)